# Reverse the word in a string with the same order in javascript without using the array functions except .length

Tags: javascript, string

I want reverse the string with the same order. We should not use the Array functions like `split(), .reverse() and .join()`. but we can use `array.length`.

Here i am attached my code. How to achieve that thing more efficiently.

```
var str = "i am javascript";
// result "i ma tpircsavaj"
function reverseString(myStr){
    var strlen = myStr.length, result = "", reverseStr = "", reverseStrArr = [];
  for(var i = strlen-1; i >= 0; i--){
    reverseStr +=  myStr[i];
  }

    for(var j = 0; j < strlen; j++){
    if(reverseStr[j] == " "){
      reverseStrArr.push(result);
      result = "";
    }else{
      result += reverseStr[j];
      if(j + 1 == strlen){
        reverseStrArr.push(result);
        result = "";
      }
    }
  }

  for(var k=reverseStrArr.length - 1; k >= 0; k--){
    result += reverseStrArr[k] + " "
  }
  console.log(result);
}
reverseString(str);
```

Comment: `push()` is an array function, is it not? :)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts. sorry we can use push(). not allow to use split, reverse and join.

Comment: I think the first for loop is enough -> `for(var i = strlen - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        reverseStr += str[i];
    }
    
    return reverseStr;`

Comment: @HasanSh. the first for loop will give "tpircsavaj ma i". not the expected result. https://jsfiddle.net/Lqk2rs79/

Comment: So you can't use array functions... but you could use `str.match(/\S+/g)`, which would give you an array of words (strings of non-space characters), you could reverse each word and concatenate the strings together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a loop, collect the characters of a word and reverse the word.

```js
function reverse(string) {
    var reversed = '';
    while (reversed.length !== string.length) {
        reversed = string[reversed.length] + reversed;
    }
    return reversed;
}

var string = "i am javascript",
    temp = '',
    result = '',
    i = 0;

while (i < string.length) {
    if (string[i] === ' ') {
        result += (result && ' ') + reverse(temp);
        temp = '';
    } else {
        temp += string[i];
    }
    i++;
}
if (temp) result += (result && ' ') + reverse(temp);

console.log(result);
```

An approach from the end.

```js
function reverse(string) {
    var reversed = '';
    while (reversed.length !== string.length) {
        reversed = string[reversed.length] + reversed;
    }
    return reversed;
}

var string = "i am javascript",
    temp = '',
    result = '',
    i = string.length;

while (i--) {
    if (string[i] === ' ') {
        result = ' ' + reverse(temp) + result;
        temp = '';
    } else {
        temp = string[i] + temp;
    }
}
if (temp) result = reverse(temp) + result;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 pointers: i to indicate the current position and j to indicate the start index of the current word. Add the reversed of current word char by char when space.

Don't be fooled by the nested loops, the complexity is the same as yours: O(n) and somehow cleaner for me.

```js
var string = "i love javascript and the whole world!"
var result = ""
var i = j = 0
var l = string.length

while (i++ < l) {
 var k = i
 if (string[i] === " " || (i === l - 1) && k++) {
  while (--k >= j) result += string[k]
  j = i + 1
  result += " "
 }
}
result = result && result.slice(0, -1) || ""


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function reverseStr(str) {
  var ret = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    ret = str[i] + ret;
  }
  return ret;
}

function doIt(str) {
  var ret = "", cur = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c == ' ' || c == '.') {
      ret += reverseStr(cur) + c;
      cur = "";      
    } else {
      cur += c;
    }
  }
  ret += reverseStr(cur);  
  return ret;
}

console.log(doIt('Reverse the word in a string with the same order in javascript without using the array functions except .length'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverse(word) {
  if (word.length > 1) {
    var newWord = '';
    for (j = word.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
      newWord += word[j];
    }
    return newWord + ' ';
  } else {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}

var text = "i am javascript";
var words = text.split(' ');
var result = '';
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  result += reverse(words[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```